# Error in batch find and replace VBA code for Power Point slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to write a `batch find and replace` code for Power Point slides in `VBA` but I'm getting the following error: `Compile Error Method or data member not found`.

The debugger is highlighting Shapes in `PP.Shapes` on line `13`.
I do not have much experience with VBA. I gathered ideas from:
 
* [Getting Started with VBA in PowerPoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814734(v=office.14).aspx) (Office Dev Center)
* [Power Point VBA-Find & Replace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYfKvVmtAGE) (YouTube)
* "Simple Macro to import slides from a file" @ (VBA Express Forum)

```
Sub BatchFindReplace()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFolderName As String
Dim PP As Presentation
'Directory
strFolderName = "C:\Users\Emma\Desktop\temp1"
strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.ppt*")
Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)

'Find and Replace Code
For Each shp In PP.Shapes
If shp.HasTextFrame Then
    If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "W", "kkk")
    End If
End If
Next

PP.Close
strFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The `VBA` tag will cover for all MS-Office applications. You do not have to tag all of them :)

Comment: Oh ok I see :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `.Shapes` is not a member of `Presentation` but of `Slide`

```
'~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)

'~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
Set PPSlide = PP.Slides(1)

For Each shp In PPSlide.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next shp
```

If you want to work with all shapes in all slides then you will have to loop through slides.

```
Dim sld As Slide

'~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)

For Each sld In PP.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
    Next shp
Next
```

Comment: With your solution I now have a working vba code :) : [link](https://pastebin.com/7BTm6jE6) @ Siddharth Rout